# Where can I find a Good Sample ASP.NET Database Driven Web Application?

Tags: c#, asp.net, database

I would like to learn the best practices to employ when creating a database driven web-application.
I prefer to learn from examples. 
What is a good sample application that I can download and run to learn this:

I am looking for:

1. Should be written in C# (preferably)
2. Should contain a complex database design (parent child relations, etc.)
3. Should implement the best practices for an ASP.net website as well as for database design.
4. Preferably uses Oracle.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you don't want to worry about writing your [DAL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_access_layer) (Data Access Layer), then I suggest looking at [Nhibernate](http://www.nhibernate.org).  There are samples with it and ASP.NET [here](http://www.beansoftware.com/asp.net-tutorials/nhibernate-log4net.aspx), [here](http://www.hibernate.org/363.html), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/259409/database-and-orm-choice-for-an-small-medium-size-net-application#259551).  Here's a [sample with just Oracle](http://www.oracle.com/technology/tech/windows/odpnet/index.html) and ASP.NET.

If you are looking for just sample ASP.NET Applications without an Object Relational Mapper like NHibernate, try [this](http://www.asp.net/Learn/data-access/).

Also, on a higher level, you're looking for an [N-Tier ASP.NET application design](http://www.developerfusion.com/article/3058/boosting-your-net-application-performance/2/).  There are good tutorials on that [here](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/tavanover/NTierDevelopmentWithNetP311282005073236AM/NTierDevelopmentWithNetP3.aspx), [here](http://www.developerfusion.com/article/3058/boosting-your-net-application-performance/2/), and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms978384.aspx).

Answer (score 3):

There are lots of examples in [ASP.NET Starter](http://www.asp.net/community/projects/) Kits.  I really like the [BlogEngine.NET](http://www.asp.net/downloads/starter-kits/blog-engine/) application.  For higher-end basics (hmmm..."higher-end basics"...oxymoron?)  the [BeerHouse E-Commerce application](http://www.asp.net/downloads/starter-kits/the-beer-house/) is great.

Answer (score 1):

For 1 through 3, I would recommend downloading some of the ASP.NET starter kits. I'm not sure if they work with Oracle though.

Some of the bigger frameworks are also great starts like DotNetNuke. They make great use of best practices.

http://www.asp.net/community/projects/

Comment: I looked into DotNetNuke for you and oracle and while I don't see any free oracle db providers there are some for pay ones out there. So I still say my answer is good for requirements 1 - 3.

Answer (score 1):

For Oracle, look for samples using the System.Data.OracleClient.

Answer (score 1):

Writing this from my iPhone so sorry for the brvity.

Check out rob conrey's MVC storefront videos & source.

Comment: hows that keyboard treating you? ;p

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion best practice would dictate the following:

1. Use an ORM for your data access layer. This should ideally be in a a separate project so it can be changed if need be.
2. Should use MVC. If you use WebForms then you will surely find that your business logic and the display logic gets mixed together.
3. Learn database design separate and apart from learning to write code.
4. Keep reviewing object oriented design fundamentals.
5. Take time to learn design patterns. Not to become a slave to "The Gang of Four" but so that you can take advantage of proven patterns to solve common problems.